# How to fix the rectangle size even though the text size changes?

Tags: tikz-styles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10pt]
  \node[draw, rounded corners, align=center, fill=blue!20, fill opacity=0.6, minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm]                        (start)   {\textbf{unknown}};

  \node[draw, below=of start, align=center, fill=blue!40, fill opacity=0.7, minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm]                        (step 1)   {\textbf{My name in Alice}\\$A+B$};

  \node[draw, below=of step 1, align=center, fill=blue!40, fill opacity=0.7, minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm]                        (step 2)   {\textbf{What about you}};


    \node[draw, below=of step 2, align=center, fill=blue!40, fill opacity=0.7, minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm]                        (step 3)   {\textbf{Bob}\\ $A+B+C+D$};



  \node[draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!40, fill opacity=0.7, below=20pt of step 3]  (end)     {End};

  \draw[arrow] (start)  -- (step 1);
  \draw[arrow] (step 1) -- (step 2);
  \draw[arrow] (step 2) -- (step 3);
  \draw[arrow] (step 3) -- (end);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see the sizes of middle three rectangles are different though I have set "minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm" , but it doesn't work, How can I fixed the same size of these rectangles?

Comment: It's  the `minimum size`  but the length of `\textbf{My name in Alice}`is 90,3657pt (3.175 cm)

Comment: You should make yourself more familiar with `tikz`. In your case read chapter *17 Nodes and Edges* on page 223 of Ti*k*Z & PGF manual. BTW, my answer on your previous question solve this problem. If you insisted to have nodes contain just in two lines (why? what is wrong if text is broken into more lines?), you need increase `text width` accordingly.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you, you have helped me a lot. I don't care about the text, I care about the size of the rectangle. I'll learn more about tikz.

Answer (score 3):

- In the node, the `ìnner sep` is initially `.3333em` (documantation `pgfmanual`
- The length of `\textbf{My name in Alice}` exceeds 3 cm
- The minimum size is: The length of `\textbf{My name in Alice}`+2x`.3333em`

Remark:

- `\tikzstyle` is depreciated
- If opacity is not useful, we can replace `fill=blue!40,fill opacity=0.7` by (after test)    `fill=blue!29`

**the code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        draw,
        align=center,
        minimum height=1cm
    },
    start/.style={      
        rounded corners,
        % fill=blue!30, 
        %fill opacity=0.6,
        fill=blue!19, 
        minimum width=2cm,
    },
    rect/.style={
        % fill=blue!40,
        % fill opacity=0.7,
        fill=blue!29,
        minimum width=3.42cm,
        },
    arrow/.style={
        thick,
        -stealth,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myconversion}{m}{%
    \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { #1 } { 1cm }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth \mylength {\textbf{My name in Alice}}
\verb| length of \textbf{My name in Alice} | \myconversion{\the\mylength}

\addtolength \mylength {0.6666em}% the initially inner sep
\verb| length of minimum width |\myconversion{\the\mylength}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10pt]
    \node[start]                        (start)     {\textbf{unknown}};
    \node[rect, below=of start]         (step 1)    {\textbf{My name in Alice}\\$A+B$};
    \node[rect, below=of step 1,]       (step 2)    {\textbf{What about you}};
    \node[rect, below=of step 2]        (step 3)    {\textbf{Bob}\\ $A+B+C+D$};
    \node[rect,below=20pt of step 3]    (end)       {End};

    \draw[arrow] (start)  -- (step 1);
    \draw[arrow] (step 1) -- (step 2);
    \draw[arrow] (step 2) -- (step 3);
    \draw[arrow] (step 3) -- (end);
\end{tikzpicture}


% test color
% \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
%     \filldraw[fill=blue!40,fill opacity=0.7] (0:1cm) circle (12mm);
%     \filldraw[fill=blue!29] (0:2cm) circle (12mm);
% \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Code (fix the same size for the rectangles):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10pt]
        \node[draw, rounded corners, align=center, fill=blue!20, fill opacity=0.6, minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm]                        (start)   {\textbf{unknown}};
        
        \node[draw, below=of start, align=center, fill=blue!40, fill opacity=0.7, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=1.5cm]                        (step 1)   {\textbf{My name in Alice}\\$A+B$};
        
        \node[draw, below=of step 1, align=center, fill=blue!40, fill opacity=0.7, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=1.5cm]                        (step 2)   {\textbf{What about you}};
        
        
        \node[draw, below=of step 2, align=center, fill=blue!40, fill opacity=0.7, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=1.5cm]                        (step 3)   {\textbf{Bob}\\ $A+B+C+D$};
        
        
        
        \node[draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!40, fill opacity=0.7, below=20pt of step 3]  (end)     {End};
        
        \draw[arrow] (start)  -- (step 1);
        \draw[arrow] (step 1) -- (step 2);
        \draw[arrow] (step 2) -- (step 3);
        \draw[arrow] (step 3) -- (end);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```